# How to assigns spaces on left side with loop

Tags: php

I am new one at PHP i am making a program this will show half pyramid on right side with hashes. Now my pyramid show on left side.here is below my code.

Code

```
<form method="post">
 Height: <input type="number" name="height"/> 
</form>
<?php 
$height=$_POST['height'];
if($height <= 0){echo "Please write Positive Number";}
 $spacing=$height -1; 
 $hashes=2; 

for ($i=0; $i<$height; $i++) 
{ 
    for ($j=$spacing; $j>0; $j--) 
    { 
        echo " "; 
    } 
    for ($k=0; $k<$hashes; $k++) 
    { 
       echo "#"; 
    } 
    $spacing--; 
    $hashes ++; 
    echo "<br/>"; 

}

  ?>
```

Result of above code If height 8.

```
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
#########
```

But i need this result i am showing below.

```
        ##
       ###
      ####
     #####
    ######
   #######
  ########
 #########
```

Any one know how to assign spaces on left side like show on above example what i want.Other thing i don't need Css to control this problem i want to handle this think with loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
for ($i=0; $i<$height; $i++) 
{ 
    for ($j=$spacing; $j>0; $j--) 
    { 
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
    } 
    for ($k=0; $k<$hashes; $k++) 
    { 
        echo "#"; 
    } 
    $spacing--; 
    $hashes ++; 
   echo "<br/>"; 

}
```

`&nbsp;` is the non-breaking space in HTML. HTML ignores spaces, this is why we use `&nbsp;`to insert multiples spaces.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.I had mention on above post i need Half pyramid not full on right side.

Comment: @user2802991 Inserting two `&nbsp;` will fix the problem. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code instead of your whole `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $height; $i++)
    echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', str_pad(str_repeat('#', $i), $height, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT)) . '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, you have, is a html problem, not a php problem. (Your code is correct.) The browser just shows one space character and discard any subsequent.

Either you wrap the whole php output in a `<pre>`tag or you have to output `&nbsp;` instead of the spaces (which is only a sufficient solution, if you use a monospace-font.)

Comment: It's worth noting that if you don't use `<pre>`, the characters won't be fixed-width - so a space will likely be narrower than a hash (or not, depending on the font). `<pre>` is the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
print '<pre>';
for ($i=1; $i<= 10; $i++) {
  print str_repeat('#', $i).'<br />';
}

for ($i=1; $i<= 10; $i++) {
  print str_repeat('&nbsp;', 10-$i).str_repeat('#', $i).'<br />';
}
print '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for using `10` ... I don't like `8` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
$height = abs($_POST['height']);

// the number of characters in each row of the shape
$width = $height + 1;

// one iteration creates one row
for($i = 0; $i < $height; $i++) {

    // the number of # symbols at the end of the row
    $hashes = $i + 2;

    // we know the width and the number of hashes, so space the difference
    echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', $width - $hashes);

    // and finally output the hashes
    echo str_repeat('#', $hashes);

    echo '<br/>';
}
```